# Google Closure introducing errors

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

**EDIT**

The lesson, learned with the help of @Alex, is that you should never put function declarations in block scope.  Not that I intended to do this, but if you slip up, it can cause big problems.

---

I have a script file that seems to be getting compressed via Google Closure incorrectly.  When I run my app with the original code, all works fine.  But when I try to compress it with Google Closure, some errors get introduced.

**I am NOT using the advanced option; I'm using the basic, default mode**

Obviously I can't expect anyone to debug the compressed file, but I'm hoping someone can look at the uncompressed code and let me know if I'm somehow doing something insanely stupid that would trick Closure.

Some notes on the minified code:

Closure is **inlining** `BEFramework.prototype.hstreamLoad` and `BEFramework.prototype.hstreamEvalJson`, and seems to be utterly removing the helper functions `getDeleteValue`, `getValueToDisplay`, `getDisplayForLabel` and likely others.

Uncompressed file is below.

This code can [manually be compiled by closure here](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home), which should reproduce the symptoms described above.

```
(function() {
    var $ = jQuery;

    // Load and display the messages ("healthstream") for a given module.
    // This requires that the module's HTML have specific features, see
    // dashboard.htm and contactsManager/details/default.htm for examples.
    // This also requires that the `request` support `pageIndex` and `pageSize`,
    // so we can handle paging.
    //
    // Args:    `options`       An options object with these keys:
    //                              `channelId`     The channel ID of the module (for transmitRequest)
    //                              `translationId` Optional alternate ID for translation (if not given,
    //                                              `channelId` is used).
    //                              `action`        The action (for transmitRequest)
    //                                                  - Must support `pageIndex` and `pageSize`
    //                              `request`       The request (for transmitRequest)
    //                                                  - Must include `pageIndex` and `pageSize`
    //                              `complete`      Optional callback triggered when the load is complete.
    //                              `showOptions`   Optional callback if an options menu is supported
    //                                              by the calling module. Receives a raw event instance
    //                                              and the item on which the options were triggered:
    //                                                  function showOptions(event, item)
    //                              `context`       Optional context (`this` value) for the call to
    //                                              `complete` and/or `showOptions`
    BEFramework.prototype.hstreamLoad = hstreamLoad;
    function hstreamLoad(options) {
        var inst = this;

        var channelId, translationId, action, request, complete, showOptions, context,
            pageIndex, pageCount, pageSize, pageCount,
            btnPrevious, btnNext,
            dataShownFlags;

        // Get our arguments (with defaults)
        channelId = options.channelId;
        translationId = options.translationId || options.channelId;
        action = options.action;
        request = $.extend({}, options.request);    // Create a *copy*, because we modify it when doing paging
        complete = options.complete;
        if (typeof complete !== "function") {
            complete = undefined;
        }
        showOptions = options.showOptions;
        if (typeof showOptions !== "function") {
            showOptions = undefined;
        }
        context = options.context;  // (undefined will automatically become the global object)

        // Grab the initial pageIndex and pageSize
        pageIndex = request.pageIndex || 1;
        pageSize = request.pageSize || 100;

        // Disable the button and show "searching" label
        $('#healthStreamSearchButton')
            .button("disable")
            .button("option", "label", BETranslate(translationId, 'HealthStreamSearching'));

        // Hook up the buttons; be a bit paranoid that they've been hooked before and clear previous handlers
        btnPrevious = $('#healthStreamPagePrevious');
        btnNext = $('#healthStreamPageNext');
        btnPrevious.hide().unbind("click.paging").bind("click.paging", goToPreviousPage);
        btnNext.hide().unbind("click.paging").bind("click.paging", goToNextPage);

        // Do it
        doLoad();

        // === Support functions

        // Trigger a load request
        function doLoad() {
            request.pageIndex = pageIndex;
            request.pageSize = pageSize;
            inst._transport.transmitRequest(channelId, action, request, hstreamLoaded);
        }

        // Hndle the load response
        function hstreamLoaded(objResponse) {
            var healthStream = objResponse.items;
            var total = objResponse.total;
            var tbody = $('#healthStreamList');

            // Need to make this update optional
            $('#pageHeaderName').html(BETranslate(translationId, 'HeaderActivity') + ' (' + String(total) + ')');
            $('#healthStreamSearchButton')
                .button("enable")
                .button("option", "label", BETranslate(translationId, 'HealthStreamSearch'));
            tbody.empty();
            btnPrevious.hide();
            btnNext.hide();

            if (healthStream.length > 0) {
                pageCount = Math.ceil(total / pageSize);

                if (pageCount > 1) {
                    if (pageIndex > 1) {
                        btnPrevious.show();
                    }
                    if (pageIndex < pageCount) {
                        btnNext.show();
                    }
                }

                var item;
                var tr;
                var tdMain;
                var daysHash = {};
                var creationDate;
                var key;
                var today = new Date();
                var yesterday = new Date();
                var msg;
                yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);

                dataShownFlags = {};

                for (var x = 0; x < healthStream.length; x++) {
                    item = healthStream[x];
                    msg = inst.hstreamEvalJson(item);

                    if (msg.length > 0) {
                        creationDate = new Date(item.CreationDate);
                        key = [creationDate.getYear(), creationDate.getMonth(), creationDate.getDate()].join('-');

                        if (!daysHash[key]) {
                            if (isDateEqual(creationDate, today)) {
                                addRowHeader(tbody, BETranslate(inst._channelId, 'HSToday'));
                            }
                            else if (isDateEqual(creationDate, yesterday)) {
                                addRowHeader(tbody, BETranslate(inst._channelId, 'HSYesterday'));
                            }
                            else {
                                addRowHeader(tbody, creationDate.toString('MM/dd/yyyy'));
                            }
                            daysHash[key] = true;
                        }

                        tr = $(
                            "<tr>" +
                                "<td class='date' style='white-space:nowrap;'>" + new Date(item.CreationDate).toString('h:mm tt') + "</td>" +
                                "<td class='main'><span class='name'>" + msg + "</span>" +
                                "</tr>"
                        );
                        tbody.append(tr);
                        if (showOptions) {
                            tr.find("td.main").prepend($("<em rel='opt'>&nbsp;</em>").click(makeShowOptionsHandler(item)));
                        }
                    }
                }

                // If any of the templates created links with a `data` attribute, hook them up
                $('#healthStreamList a[data]').click(showTitle).each(function (index) {
                    this.id = 'data' + index;
                });

            }
            else {
                tbody.html('<tr><td colspan="2">' + BETranslate(inst._channelId, 'HSNoActivity') + '</td></tr>');
            }

            // Trigger completion callback
            if (complete) {
                complete.call(context, objResponse);
            }
        }

        function makeShowOptionsHandler(item) {
            // Our event comes to us from jQuery, but we pass on the raw
            // event to the callback
            return function (event) {
                showOptions.call(context, event.originalEvent || event, item);
            };
        }

        function addRowHeader(listRef, name) {
            listRef.append(
                "<tr>" +
                    "<td colspan='2' class='divider'>" + name + "</td>" +
                    "</tr>"
            );
        }

        function showTitle(event) {

            $.stopEvent(event);

            var link = this;
            var $link = $(this);
            var href = $link.attr("href");  // We want the attribute, not the property (the property is usually expanded)
            var hrefTitle = $link.attr('hreftitle') || BETranslate(inst._channelId, 'HSMoreInfo');
            var data = $link.attr('data') || "";
            var linkId = link.id;

            if (!dataShownFlags[linkId]) {
                dataShownFlags[linkId] = true;
                if (data) {
                    var div = $(
                        "<div class='data'>" +
                            "<span data-linkId='" + linkId + "' class='close'>x</span>" +
                            "<table><thead></thead></table>" +
                            "</div>"
                    );
                    $link.parent().append(div);

                    var thead = div.find("thead");
                    var arr = data.split('~');
                    var splitEntry;

                    for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
                        splitEntry = arr[x].split('|');
                        if (splitEntry[0] === 'Changed length') {
                            splitEntry[1] = splitEntry[1].replace(/\d+/g, BEFramework.prettyTime);
                        }
                        if (splitEntry.length > 1 && splitEntry[1].length > 0) {
                            thead.append(
                                "<tr>" +
                                    "<td class='hslabel'>" + splitEntry[0] + ":</td>" +
                                    "<td>" + splitEntry[1] + "</td>" +
                                    "</tr>"
                            );
                        }
                    }

                    div.find("span:first").click(hideTitle);

                    if (href && href !== "#") {
                        $("<a target='_blank'>" + hrefTitle + "</a>").attr("href", href).appendTo(div);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        function hideTitle(event) {
            var $this = $(this),
                linkId = $this.attr("data-linkId");
            delete dataShownFlags[linkId];
            $this.parent().remove();
            return false;
        }

        function goToPreviousPage(event) {
            --pageIndex;
            doLoad();
            return false;
        }
        function goToNextPage(event) {
            ++pageIndex;
            doLoad();
            return false;
        }
    }

    var ___x = false;
    var __i = 0;

    BEFramework.prototype.hstreamEvalJson = hstreamEvalJson;
    function hstreamEvalJson(item) {
        var inst = this;

        if (item.Action === 'saveinsurance' && !___x && __i != 0){
            var start = +new Date();
            __i = 1;
        }

        var userId = inst._BEUser ? inst._BEUser.getId() : -1;
        var json = eval('(' + item.JSON + ')');
        var key = 'HS' + item.Module + '_' + item.Action;
        var msg = BETranslate(inst._channelId, key);
        var fromIsMe = item.CreatedByContactId == userId;
        var toIsMe = item.ContactId == userId;
        var fromString = (fromIsMe) ? '<strong>' + BETranslate(inst._channelId, 'HSYou') + '</strong>' : '<a class="vcard" contactId="' + item.CreatedByContactId + '">' + item.CreatedByName + '</a>';
        var toString = (toIsMe) ? '<strong>' + BETranslate(inst._channelId, 'HSYour') + '</strong>' : '<a class="vcard" contactId="' + item.ContactId + '">' + item.ContactName + '</a>';
        var fromString2 = (fromIsMe) ? '<strong>' + BETranslate(inst._channelId, 'HSYour').toLowerCase() + '</strong>' : '<a class="vcard" contactId="' + item.CreatedByContactId + '">' + item.CreatedByName + '</a>';
        var toString2 = (toIsMe) ? '<strong>' + BETranslate(inst._channelId, 'HSYou').toLowerCase() + '</strong>' : '<a class="vcard" contactId="' + item.ContactId + '">' + item.ContactName + '</a>';
        var subFormat, subProps;
        var configObject = (BEFramework.healthStreamConfig[item.Module] && BEFramework.healthStreamConfig[item.Module][item.Action]) || {};
        var standardCase = configObject.standardCase;
        var suppress = configObject.suppress || [];
        var propertiesInOrder = configObject.displayOrder || [];

        if (msg.indexOf('not found in module') != -1) {
            try {
                switch (item.Module) {
                    case 'contacts':
                        if (item.Action == 'setpermission' || item.Action == 'deleterelationship' || item.Action == 'addinvite') {
                            msg = BETranslate(inst._channelId, key + json.type.toString());
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'tasks':
                        if (item.Action == 'savetask') {
                            msg = BETranslate(inst._channelId, key + json.type.toString());
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        msg = '';
                }
            } catch (ex) {
                msg = '';
            }
        }

        for (var prop in json) {
            if (typeof (json[prop]) == 'object') {

                if (prop === 'changes' || prop === 'deleted'){
                    subProps = json[prop];

                    for (var propName in subProps) {
                        if (indexInArrayCI(propName, propertiesInOrder) === -1 && indexInArrayCI(propName, suppress) === -1){
                            propertiesInOrder.push(propName);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (prop == 'changes') {
                    var changes = '';
                    var changeFrom = BETranslate(inst._channelId, 'HSChangedFrom');
                    var changeTo = BETranslate(inst._channelId, 'HSChangedTo');

                    for (var i = 0; i < propertiesInOrder.length; i++) {
                        var subprop = propertiesInOrder[i];
                        if (getObjectValCI(subProps, subprop) == null) continue;

                        var subSplit = stripHtml(getObjectValCI(subProps, subprop)).split('|');

                        if (subSplit.length === 1) {
                            subFormat = BETranslate(inst._channelId, 'HS' + item.Module + '_changes_' + subprop);
                            if (subFormat.indexOf('not found in module') < 0) {
                                changes += $.sandr(subFormat, '#{value}', subSplit[0]);
                            }
                            else {
                                changes += "*|" + subprop + " " + subSplit[0] + "~";
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            var fromValue = stripHtml(subSplit[0]);
                            var toValue = stripHtml(subSplit[1]);

                            var packetInfo = processChangedValues(subprop, fromValue, toValue);
                            if (packetInfo.skip) continue;

                            changes = changes + changeFrom + packetInfo.display + '|' + packetInfo.fromValue + '<b>' + changeTo + '</b>' + packetInfo.toValue + '~';
                        }
                    }

                    msg = $.sandr(msg, '#{' + prop + '}', changes);
                } else if (prop == 'deleted') {
                    var deleted = '';

                    for (var i = 0; i < propertiesInOrder.length; i++) {
                        var subprop = propertiesInOrder[i];
                        var currentValue = getObjectValCI(subProps, subprop);

                        if (currentValue == null || currentValue.toString().length === 0) continue;

                        deleted = deleted + getDisplayForLabel(subprop) + '|' + getDeleteValue(subprop, currentValue) + '~';
                    }

                    msg = $.sandr(msg, '#{' + prop + '}', deleted);
                }
            } else {
                msg = $.sandr(msg, '#{' + prop + '}', $.sandr(json[prop], '"', ' '));
            }

            function processChangedValues(label, fromValue, toValue){
                var typeFormat = (getObjectValCI(configObject, label) || {}).type;
                var result = {};

                if (typeFormat === 'date'){
                    var d1 = new Date(fromValue);
                    var d2 = new Date(toValue);

                    if (isDateEqual(d1, d2)) result.skip = true;
                }

                result.fromValue = getValueToDisplay(fromValue, typeFormat);
                result.toValue = getValueToDisplay(toValue, typeFormat);

                result.display = getDisplayForLabel(label)

                return result;
            }

            function getDeleteValue(label, value){
                var typeFormat = (getObjectValCI(configObject, label) || {}).type;

                return getValueToDisplay(value, typeFormat);
            }

            function getValueToDisplay(rawValue, typeFormat){
                if (typeFormat === 'date'){
                    var d = new Date(rawValue);
                    return isNaN(d.getTime()) ? rawValue : d.toString('MM/dd/yyyy');
                } else if (typeof typeFormat === 'function') {
                    return typeFormat(rawValue)
                } else {
                    return rawValue;
                }
            }

            function getDisplayForLabel(label){
                var fixCaseOfProperty = standardCase === '*' || indexInArrayCI(label, standardCase) > -1;
                var rawConfigForLabel = getObjectValCI(configObject, label) || {};

                return (rawConfigForLabel && rawConfigForLabel.display)
                        || (fixCaseOfProperty ? fixCase(label) : null)
                        || label;
            }
        }

        msg = $.sandr(msg, '#{contactId}', item.ContactId);
        msg = $.sandr(msg, '#{from}', fromString);
        msg = $.sandr(msg, '#{to}', toString);
        msg = $.sandr(msg, '#{from2}', fromString2);
        msg = $.sandr(msg, '#{to2}', toString2);
        msg = $.sandr(msg, '#{recordId}', item.RecordId);

        msg = msg.replace(/#{[\S]*}/g, '');

        if (item.Action === 'saveinsurance' && !___x && __i == 1){
            var end = +new Date();
            ___x = true;
            //alert(end - start);
        }

        if (item.Action === 'saveinsurance') __i++;

        if (msg.indexOf('not found in module') == -1) {
            return msg;
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }

    function stripHtml(html) {
        var tmp = document.createElement('DIV');
        tmp.innerHTML = html;
        return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText;
    }

    function isDateEqual(date1, date2) {
        if (date1.getDate() === date2.getDate() &&
            date1.getMonth() === date2.getMonth() &&
            date1.getYear() === date2.getYear()) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function getObjectValCI(obj, key){
        for (var k in obj){
            if (k.toLowerCase() === key.toLowerCase()){
                return obj[k];
            }
        }
    }

    function indexInArrayCI(item, arr){
        if (!$.isArray(arr)) arr = [];

        var target = item.toString().toLowerCase();

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            if (target === arr[i].toLowerCase()) return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    function fixCase(str){
        return str.replace(/[a-z][A-Z]/g, function(match) { return match.charAt(0) + ' ' + match.charAt(1).toLowerCase(); }).toLowerCase()
            .replace(/\sid\s/g, ' ID ')
            .replace(/\sid$/g,  ' ID')
            .replace(/^id$/g,  'ID');
    }
})();
```

Comment: Are you using Advanced Optimization?

Comment: For testing have you tried other compressors like the YUI Compressor?

Comment: @zaf - no, but I guess that's a good idea

Comment: @alex23 - it's very old js code that I was making a few improvements too.  I could improve it in a million ways, but I don't see anything crazy in there that should be killing minification.

Comment: Have you tried using the closure inspector to debug? What sort of errors are you getting? Are you saying that you believe your problems are being caused by the compiler removing the functions you mention?

Comment: @AdamRackis: When I compile that with the [online compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) in simple mode, `hstreamLoad` [is not inlined](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/code/jsc3f8f45018b1b314685adc3e08cb0f046/default.js), it's still there on the `BEFramework` prototype.

Comment: @urbananimal - the error is `undefined is not a function`.  I *assume* the errors is closely related to the complete removing of some of these helper functions

Comment: Have you tried protecting them using @expose?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - are you sure?  I just copied it from my question, pasted it into the link you put, kept the simple default, and I see this: `BEFramework.prototype.hstreamLoad=function(a){function d(){j.pageIndex=`

Comment: Documentation would disagree. https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler

Comment: @AdamRackis: I'm not following you. If a function is inlined, that means that it is removed and its code is repeated wherever it used to be called. Since `hstreamLoad` exists in the compiled output, it has not been inlined. You seem to be confirming what I said, that it isn't being inlined.

Comment: @T.J. - I was using the wrong terminology.  My function declaration was changed to a function expression.  `B.prototype.foo = functionName;` was changed to `B.prototype.foo = function() { ... };`

Comment: @AdamRackis: *"My function declaration was changed to a function expression."* Right, yeah, that's not inlining (in the compiler sense of the word). Closure will do all sorts of things like that, that's part of the point of using it. It shouldn't make a difference when you call `hstreamLoad` on a `BEFramework` instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are too many errors to think of. First of all, I don't understand if you want static reference or instantiated values. You are not using jsDoc tags or anything like that. The Compiler does it's best work only with the corresponding jsDoc tag. You're logic is very weird and ill formulated. Prototype alternations, etc, all happening in an IIFE(immediately invoked function expression). Are your functions static? Are they constructors? Are we human or are we dancer?

an IIFE executes before the DOMContentLoaded event is fired by the browser. The most you can do is a jQuery IIFE equivalent `$(function() {})();` which binds that to the DOMReady or DOMContentLoaded callback. You are defining inline functions inside blocks, which is not even in the ECMA Language.

While most script engines support Function Declarations within blocks it is not part of ECMAScript (see [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), clause 13 and 14). Worse implementations are inconsistent with each other and with future EcmaScript proposals. ECMAScript only allows for Function Declarations in the root statement list of a script or function. Instead use a variable initialized with a Function Expression to define a function within a block.

```
var myFunctionName = function (params) {};
```

You are also missing loads of semi-colons. Automatic semi-colon insertion on interpretation of your JS is not exactly flawless, so make a habit out of it.

Relying on implicit insertion can cause subtle, hard to debug problems. Don't do it. You're better than that.

There are a couple places where missing semicolons are particularly dangerous:

```
// 1.
MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function() {
  return 42;
}  // No semicolon here.

(function() {
  // Some initialization code wrapped in a function to create a scope for locals.
})();


var x = {
  'i': 1,
  'j': 2
}  // No semicolon here.

// 2.  Trying to do one thing on Internet Explorer and another on Firefox.
// I know you'd never write code like this, but throw me a bone.
[normalVersion, ffVersion][isFF]();


var THINGS_TO_EAT = [apples, oysters, sprayOnCheese]  // No semicolon here.

// 3. conditional execution a la bash
-1 == resultOfOperation() || die();
```

So what happens?

JavaScript error - first the function returning 42 is called with the second function as a parameter, then the number 42 is "called" resulting in an error.
You will most likely get a 'no such property in undefined' error at runtime as it tries to call `x[ffVersion][isIE]()`.
die is called unless `resultOfOperation()` is `NaN` and `THINGS_TO_EAT` gets assigned the result of `die()`.
Why?

JavaScript requires statements to end with a semicolon, except when it thinks it can safely infer their existence. In each of these examples, a function declaration or object or array literal is used inside a statement. The closing brackets are not enough to signal the end of the statement. Javascript never ends a statement if the next token is an infix or bracket operator.

This has really surprised people, so make sure your assignments end with semicolons.

Comment: Please point to one major JS implementation that has ASI flaws. I'm not aware of any.

Comment: You're quite right about those function declarations within the `if` block, that is absolutely not allowed. But perhaps it would have been possible to be a bit more polite (throughout)? More flies with honey and all that...

Comment: @alex23 - don't assume the person criticizing downvoted.  That's often not the case.  Having said that, +1.  Thank you for pointing out the flaws in there.

Comment: Well thanks again.  I've got the compressed file prettified, and I plan to step through it.  If the problem is anything caused by an error pointed out in your answer I'll mark this as accepted.

Comment: @user1689607: (Not following, what is it you think alex23 downvoted? What would make a downvote a "rampage"?) You can never be sure who downvoted (or upvoted) anything, unless you're the one who did the downvoting. :-) It's dangerous to assume anything. Lots of people downvote without commenting, and lots of people comment without downvoting. Sometimes people do both, but I doubt it's all that common and in fact there are people who feel strongly that no one should do it (there's a discussion about it somewhere on meta).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Yes, you can't be sure, but the timing can certainly raise flags. I few minutes after my comment, all my questions were down-voted. It'll be interesting to see what happens when there's a reversal.

Comment: @user1689607: If someone really went through your questions and downvoted them all, don't worry, the SO bots'll fix it (and the user). :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Yeah, that's what I meant by reversal. @@alex: Then my apologies.

Comment: Well, how about that.  The problem was the function declarations declared in block scope all along.  Thank you very, very much Alex.

Answer (score 2):

When you use closure compiler you're giving up some control over your code. It will do all sorts of tricks, and potentially remove unused code.

It appears as though your functions are not removed, but are renamed.

For example, your call to `getDeleteValue`...

```
getDeleteValue(subprop, currentValue)
```

is now...

```
l(g,r)
```

Because `getDeleteValue` was not exported, Closure renamed it.

Working with Closure Compiler takes a bit of finesse and quite a bit of documentation scouring until you're familiar with how it works.

Comment: Gah - fair enough.  Is it normal for Closure to inline a function declaration like that though? There definitely is an error *somewhere*

Comment: @AdamRackis: I'm not sure you're using the word "inline" correctly. See my note on the question.

Comment: @AdamRackis: If you mean the fact that it did a direct assignment to the prototype, then I would say I'm not surprised, but I would expect it to still honor however it was originally used.